# How do I set a column value to NULL in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

How do I clear the value from a cell and make it NULL?

Answer (score 230, accepted):

If you've opened a table and you want to clear an existing value to NULL, click on the value, and press <kbd>`Ctrl`</kbd>+<kbd>`0`</kbd>.

Answer (score 446):

I think Zack [properly answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/444658/1165522)  the question but just to cover all the bases:

```
Update myTable set MyColumn = NULL
```

This would set the entire column to null as the Question Title asks.

To set a specific row on a specific column to null use:

```
Update myTable set MyColumn = NULL where Field = Condition.
```

This would set a specific cell to null as the inner question asks.

Answer (score 53):

If you are using the table interface you can type in NULL (all caps)

otherwise you can run an update statement where you could:

```
Update table set ColumnName = NULL where [Filter for record here]
```

Answer (score 13):

Use This:

```
Update Table Set Column = CAST(NULL As Column Type) where Condition
```

Like This:

```
Update News Set Title = CAST(NULL As nvarchar(100)) Where ID = 50
```

Comment: Care to explain why your answer is better than the others? I mean you post this about almost half a year later.

Answer (score 7):

Ctrl+0 or empty the value and hit enter.

Comment: Emptying the value and clicking enter will not create a NULL value.  If the column is a string datatype (varchar and the like), it will create an empty string.  If the column is a numeric datatype (int and the like) it will pop up an Invalid Value error. And so on.  NULL is the absence of a value, and is does not mean "blank."

Answer (score 3):

Just as a little extension to Jeff Martin's and Zack Peterson's solution.

If you still want to set several values from the columns to `null` you can simply set the query to

```
UPDATE myTable SET MyColumn1 = NULL, MyColumn2 = NULL, MyColumn3 = NULL, ...
```

Answer (score -1):

CTRL+0 doesn't seem to work when connected to an Azure DB.

However, to create an empty string, you can always just hit 'anykey then delete' inside a cell.

Comment: This not working in Azure DB is because the Ctrl+0 shortcut is specific to SSMS (and its predecessor, Enterprise Manager). Azure SQL Server features are all built in an entirely new interface on the web.