# how to delete a value from a column in SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

How can I delete only the field of a column without deleting the entire row? I have a table that owns the fields:
ID, Name, Mail, Phone, Company and Would like to delete only the email of a person without deleting all the fields.

If I use:

```
DELETE FROM TEST_TABLE WHERE MAIL = 'myemail@gmail.com'
```

that way will delete everything and I want to delete just the email

Comment: Update to null or '' rather than delete

Comment: Don't update to an empty string, use NULL for non-existing values.

Comment: BTW. your table has _columns_, not fields.

Comment: Also, are you using MySQL or Teradata?

Comment: I'm using teradata, I just wanted to understand how it works because it was with the thought in DELETE and not in UPDATE, thanks for the help @jarlh

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

```
Update myTable set MyColumn = NULL where Field = Condition.
```

**References**

1- [How do I set a column value to NULL in SQL Server Management Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444657/how-do-i-set-a-column-value-to-null-in-sql-server-management-studio)

2- [UPDATE, DELETE, and INSERT Statements in SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/update-delete-and-insert-statements?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Note that OP is using Teradata or perhaps MySQL. So MS SQL Server links can be a bit misleading.

Comment: Perfect, solved my problems, thank u very much for your help :D

Answer (score 0):

try

```
UPDATE
  TEST_TABLE 
SET
  MAIL = ''
WHERE
  id = your_id
```

or

if you want delete the field

```
ALTER TABLE TEST_TABLE 
DROP COLUMN MAIL;
```

Comment: Don't update to an empty string, use NULL for non-existing values.

Comment: @jarlh, in MySql you can't set field as NULL using a  NULL value. In this case, use 'NULL' (string), or empyt value instead

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=a2501b2c15ba508bf0f26ba195362e52

Comment: in pure sql it works fine, but in programming languages, ORMs parsing doesn't allow NULL values like that

Comment: OP asked for an SQL answer. (BTW, OP has now specified that Teradata, not MySQL, is used.)

Comment: @jarlh now that i saw that he is using teradata. in this case I don't know how NULL works. tks

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice to update the field with a NULL instead of leaving it blank, this indicates that there is a missing value and will later allow you to do queries where something is NOT NULL, which will give better results if it isn't returning bad data. Remember, garbage in, garbage out.

```
UPDATE TEST_TABLE SET MAIL = NULL WHERE MAIL = 'myemail@gmail.com'
```